# Referring to previous value in foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

I'm not exactly sure how to word this. I'll start off by showing you the code/API

```
$ips = array("IP1", "IP2");
        foreach ($ips as $ip) {
            $location = get_geolocation($apiKey, $ip);
            $decodedLocation = json_decode($location, true);

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$decodedLocation['ip']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$decodedLocation['continent_name']." (".$decodedLocation['continent_code'].")</td>";
            echo "<td>".$decodedLocation['country_name']." (".$decodedLocation['country_code2'].")</td>";
            echo "<td>".$decodedLocation['organization']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$decodedLocation['isp']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$decodedLocation['languages']."</td>";
            if($decodedLocation['is_eu'] == true) {
                echo "<td>Yes</td>";
            } else {
                echo "<td>No</td>";
            }
            echo "<td>".$decodedLocation['currency']['name']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$decodedLocation['time_zone']['name']."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
```

I want to be able to compare the IP1 information to IP2. For example, I want to see if the Country Name of IP1 matches the Country Name of IP2 after the loop.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 2 or more ip's, then it is better to store them in an array called `$decodedLocations` which

as key => value pairs has "ip" => "decodedLocation of the ip".
Then you can perform any comparison as you like in this new array.
To do this simply add `$decodedLocations["$ip"]=$decodedLocation;` to your foreach loop as below:

```
$ips = array("IP1", "IP2");
foreach ($ips as $ip) {
  $location = get_geolocation($apiKey, $ip);
  $decodedLocation = json_decode($location, true);
  $decodedLocations["$ip"]=$decodedLocation;
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>".$decodedLocation['ip']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$decodedLocation['continent_name']." (".$decodedLocation['continent_code'].")</td>";
  echo "<td>".$decodedLocation['country_name']." (".$decodedLocation['country_code2'].")</td>";
  echo "<td>".$decodedLocation['organization']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$decodedLocation['isp']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$decodedLocation['languages']."</td>";
  if($decodedLocation['is_eu'] == true) {
    echo "<td>Yes</td>";
  } else {
    echo "<td>No</td>";
  }
  echo "<td>".$decodedLocation['currency']['name']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$decodedLocation['time_zone']['name']."</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

Now you can compare any values as you want, like

```
if ($decodedLocations[$ips[0]]['country_name'] == $decodedLocations[$ips[1]]['country_name']) {
  // Code ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the last value in a variable:

```
$ips = [ 'ip1', 'ip2' ];
$lastIp = null;

foreach ($ips as $ip) {
    // Check if last ip is filled (on first iteration it will be null)
    if ($lastIp) {
        // Your logic using lastIp here
    }

    $lastIp = $ip;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not exactly sure if I've utilised this correctly. How would I then compare the first iteration of the loop to the last? For example:

`if($decodedLocation['continent_name'] == $lastIp['continent_name']) {
     echo "Match";
    }`